# How to invoke a REST API when an object arrives on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

S3 can be configured to invoke lambda when an object arrives in it.

Is it possible to invoke a REST API (endpoint of a microservice running in EKS) when an object arrives in S3?

Answer (score 3):

From November 2021 is possible to [integrate S3 with Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-amazon-s3-event-notifications-with-amazon-eventbridge/).
So you can create an EventBridge rule which is triggered on bucket object creation and has [API destination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-destinations-with-amazon-eventbridge/) as a target.

For this, the option Bucket Properties -> Amazon EventBridge -> "Send notifications to Amazon EventBridge for all events in this bucket" should be enabled.

Then, on EventBridge create the rule with an event pattern like this:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["<my-bucket-name>"]
    }
  }
}
```

And configure the target as API destination endpoint (configure http method, endpoint, authorization).

Comment: Thanks much! Would you have a more detailed example? How to pass the S3 object to the HTTP endpoint?

Comment: The event information (like S3 object metadata) is passed to the target (lambda, sns, sqs or in this case the http endpoint). You do not need further configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an SNS topic as a target for the event from S3. In the SNS topic, you can add an HTTP/s subscriber, which can be your API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have the Lambda hit the REST API for you.

Comment: I have a requirement to move thousands of log files every day from 1 AWS account to another. When they arrive in S3, i would like a process to be triggered which would move the logs. But Lambda needs an ip and I would have only < 10 ips left in my VPC. So lambda is having a huge performance bottleneck. THought microservices would be better to handle the movement using multiple threads/services.

Comment: @Biju if you only have 10 ips left in your VPC then your VPC is misconfigured and you need to fix that.

Comment: Does the Lambda function even need to be connected to your VPC? Also, if you're simply replicating a bucket from one account to another then there are [other ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html) to do that within S3 itself.

Comment: Yeah you want replication at that point.